# Remove %2F from 301 Redirect mod_rewrite

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I would like there not to be `%2F` after the redirect.

Currently, when I visit the link on my iPad in Safari it redirects me to `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=latepoint&route_name=dashboard__for_agent%2F` instead of `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=latepoint&route_name=dashboard__for_agent` therefore showing 404. It seems to be adding a `/` at the end when I visit on my iPad which then changes to `%2F`.

How can I remove/ensure there is no slash or %2F when this redirect happens? This issue does not occur on my Macbook Pro when I'm using Chrome, however, it does occur on my iPad when I'm using Safari. If I manually put a `/` at the end of the URL on my Macbook using Chrome then it changes to `%2F` and shows 404 just like my iPad does.

**My .htaccess looks like this**

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /login /wp-admin/admin.php?page=latepoint&route_name=dashboard__for_agent
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below code in the Htaccess file, maybe it will work for you -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/%2F/?$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Already tried it and unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Ok, Please try with this code, maybe it will work - 

Add this code below the RewriteEngine On line, add:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]